# How to split a string entirely, but keep instances where letters repeat twice together?

Tags: python, split

I have a string like:

```
s = 'aaabcdedddd'
```

In this example, I would want to split the string into something like this.

```
s = ['aa', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'dd', 'dd']
```

Notice how the three-letter repeat of `'aaa'` is not kept together, but rather considered a double repeat + a single letter (`'aa'` + `'a'`. The `'dddd'` at the end is considered double repeat + double repeat (`'dd'` + `'dd'`).

Is there any way to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 6):

One possible solution is to use `re` module ([link to Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OnAtSf/2)):

```py
import re

s = "aaabcdedddd"

print([m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(r"(.)(?:\1)?", s)])
```

Prints:

```
['aa', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'dd', 'dd']
```

---

Regex explanation `(.)(?:\1)?`:

`(.)` - match any character into capturing group 1

`(?:\1)?` - optionally match the same character as in capturing group 1. `(?: )` means non-capturing group. **Note:** I'm using non-capturing group here because second capturing group isn't needed. The regex could be then written like `r"(.)\1?"`

We are using `re.finditer()` to iterate over all matches and use `.group(0)` to get full matched string.

Comment: Might be useful to explain why a non-capturing group is required.

Comment: @MatBailie I've edited the answer. But I see what do you mean, the regex could be written `r"(.)\1?"`

Answer (score 3):

When iterating through the string:

- either you update the last list element's value (2 * char) if it is only one character long and already contains *char*,
- or you add the output list a new element thus the last index is increased for next iteration.

```
s = "aaabcdedddd"
out = [s[0]]

for char in s[1:]:
    if out[-1] == char:
        out[-1] = 2 * char
    else:
        out.append(char)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
['aa', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'dd', 'dd']
```

Comment: @Mark edited ^^ you're absolutely right  lol  it was from a previous test and I didn't notice what was necessary ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach: iterate through the string and remember the last character. If last and current are the same, then we process it a little differently. Code:

```py
s = 'aaabcdedddd'
out = []
last = None
for current in s:
    if current == last:
        # Case: When the current char is the same as the last char
        out.pop()  # Remove the last char
        current = current * 2  # Double up this current char
    out.append(current)
    last = current
print(out)
```

Output:

```py
['aa', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'dd', 'dd']
```

## Update

Thank you to Kelley Bundy for the comment, which is really misleading. I looked into my own approach and came up with a simpler one:

```py
s = 'aaabcdedddd'
out = []
for current in s:
    if out and current == out[-1]:
        out[-1] = current * 2
    else:
        out.append(current)
print(out)
```

The algorithm this time is: for each char, if it is the same as the last one we place in the output list (the `out` variable), then go ahead double it up. Otherwise, simply add it to the list.

Comment: Regex will massively outperform a native python loop. Even a generator yielding characters/pairs (rather than using append) would surely be better?

Comment: Thank you very much. All these solutions work very well.

Comment: @MatBailie agreed about the list manipulations, but my tests with a generator in a loop beats the regex solution (which also has a loop) pretty handily for this.

Comment: Performance aside, I believe that my code is easier to understand. In general, I will choose readability over performance, unless I have good reason to aim for performance.

Comment: @Mark Can you share your test code?

Comment: @HaiVu Actually I think this has somewhat *bad* readability, is misleading. Your comment describes `current == last` as *"When the current char is the same as the last char"*, but `last` isn't necessarily the last char but often the last **two chars**.